# pros and cons of calculations on the db vs on the front end

Tags: postgresql

I am fairly new to web development. When I am making a web site that shows metrics and stats/charts from data stored to a PostgreSQL db, is it better to make multiple queries to the same table for each individual stat/char and keep the js logic simple or is it a better idea to make one query from the table and aggregate the data in the front end for the different charts/stats. My intuition is to do the latter since we can get a lot of stats in one pass from the front end and we won't be crowding the db with numerous calculations especially if the web site is viewed by a lot of people. Please let me know what you think.

ie `select min(column), max(column), avg(column) from table` vs `select column from table` then calculate min/max/avg.

Comment: Honestly the real answer here is "to find out why, run them", ideally a few times and concurrently. One of these will be (much) slower than the other. Database software is heavily optimized for running functions like these on huge datasets. Programming languages (generally) are not.

Comment: What if your table has 100 million rows? Do you really want to load all those rows into your frontend just to calculate 3 numbers?

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I did some more reading on databases and front ends and realized that the typical way is to do calculations on the database side and use tools like graphql to make sure we don't over/under query. The front end should be as light as possible since some end users might not even have the processing power to do calculations. Thanks Everyone !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a generic question and it is hard to give a generic answer. It really depends on what type of data you have, what database engine you use or what computations you do.

If you only do the standard stats like you show in your example (min, max, count, avg, sum), it is definitely preferred to use database. The main reasons are:

1. **Less data transferred** between db and your app (only a summary numbers vs the whole table(s) content).
2. **Performance** - db, if structured properly, has indexes and thus operations like count, min or max will be much faster than doing the same in the code that has no information about the structure of the data.
3. **Caching** - if you have many queries of the same type, db engine will most likely have implemented some type of caching and thus doesn't have to do the calculation every time, many requests can be served directly from the cache. However, as I've said at the top, this depends on the type of data and performed operations. Will work well with mostly static data, not so well with datasets that change often.

Hope it helps, I would suggest you to read more about how db works in general, what type optimisations are utilised and so on. Will give you more understanding what's happening under the hood and better idea of the implementation that suits your problem the best.

Comment: If you add that C code in the database is faster than Java or Python code in the front end, and that procedural processing (which is sometimes the best approach) can be done in database functions, you have got all the points for doing it in the database.

Comment: That is most likely true, however, the question doesn't specify the language used for querying the db. It can be also be C or Fortran and thus be faster than the db engine itself :-)

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I did some more reading on databases and front ends and realized that the typical way is to do calculations on the database side and use tools like graphql to make sure we don't over/under query. The front end should be as light as possible since some end users might not even have the processing power to do calculations. Thanks @Vočko and all for clearing this up for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the former. What if your table has a lot of data in it, the response you will get will be colossal and it's not efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Doing such calculations on the database is better than doing it on the application layer, because it is more <strike>scalable</strike> efficient that way.

Example: Imagine a table having a million entries.

1. The 1 million entries will have to be transported to your application layer which would most probably run on another machine, which results in:

   - High bandwidth utilization
   - High latency to get that data
   - High load on your application layer (imagine doing 5 such requests simultaneously)
2. Databases are generally optimized for such aggregations:

   - [Databases use indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) (may have to create manually) to achieve results for such queries in much less than O(n) time.

Comment: But all the calculations happen in the database, and the database is harder to scale than the front end. I am not saying that your conclusion is wrong, but scalability seems to be a weak argument.

Comment: Bringing all the data to the application layer will warrant for more resources being consumed for the same calculation compared to how much resources a database will use for the same task. I agree I should have said "efficient".

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb:  "always make the database-engine do the work."  Because the database-engine has *direct access* to the data, and does not have to "send it down the wire."

Please don't overlook the sever-side option of a "stored procedure."  Although these facilities vary considerably from one server to another and are typically fairly limited on all of them, they *do* offer you the possibility of executing "programmed code" on the server, which can return results to you row-by-row.  (Such "stored procs" can also be used to prepare tables for your later consumption.)

*"Network bandwidth is expensive."*

Answer (score 1):

Doing as much as possible on the backend is known to be a good practice since you are sure that your using the actual data rather than a data you'd have to display especially if you have a lot of data. The purpose on a frontend in a website is mostly to display data and work on how it is going to be displayed. Unless you want to do something extremely complicated that you believe your database can't handle or it would be too hard to do in your database alone.